# Within subset copy one minimum value to new column in attribute table in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcmap

I have large sized spatial joined data of 75000 rows and I want to add a new column in my attributes table, named 'ITID_1', In this picture of attribute table; 'class1' is value, 'ITID' is subset and 'ITID_1' is a column to be calculated. 
I want to copy only one minimum value from 'class1' which are within subset 'ITID' to new column 'ITID_1' and update this new column 'ITID_1'. So what should I do? I tried to do this task in other GIS platforms with many helping hands but I didn't.

If the question isn't clear to understand, May this picture describe clearly what I want to do.

[image]

Comment: A picture is nice, but we need your code. This seems simple enough for a DA SearchCursor to locate the minimum and a DA UpdateCursor to populate it, but you could use a calculator as well.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to describe your code. Don't forget to use the `{}` button to format it legibly.

Comment: @BERA, at new column "ITID_1" I want to copy either minimum "class1" or "ITID". Where "ITID" is in the same row of minimum "class1" so I want to copy "ITID" instead of "class1".

Comment: Ok. So in your example, all rows where class1 is 1, you want to copy itid to itid1

Answer (score 3):

Use arcpy and the da.SearchCursor to find minimum class1, and da.UpdateCursor to copy values:

```py
import arcpy
fc = r'C:\data.gdb\somefeatureclassortable' #Change

#Find min class1 value
minclass1 = min([i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'class1')])

#Update ITID_1 with ITID value where class1 equals minclass1
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,['class1','ITID','ITID_1']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0]==minclass1:
            row[2]=row[1]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```